# Entity Framework 4 Adding an entity with reference to already existing object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a problem with Entity Framework 4 when adding a new entity with reference via navigator to an already existing one. Please take a look at the code:

```
            ControlPolicy cp1 = new ControlPolicy()
            {
                ControlPolicyLevelType = 2, //full access to NA
                MemberState = context.Countries.First(tt => tt.IsMemberState),
                OperaModuleType = 2,
                MemberStateIncluded = true,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedByUserId = 1,
            };
            context.ControlPolicies.AddObject(cp1);

            context.SaveChanges();
```

The error is:

> A relationship from the 'ControlPolicy_MemberState_Country_' AssociationSet is in the 'Added' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Country' must also in the 'Added' state.

When I look at the ChangeTracker the ControlPolicy object is in fact in 'Added' state, while the Country one is in 'Undefined' state. I think that is correct - after all I do not add a new object, I only want to refer to existing country.

Comment: Do you have a MemberStateId property (foreign key)? Try setting that property instead of setting the association.

Comment: No, I don't have such property, only the navigator.

Comment: You should add the foreign key to the model, it will save you a lof of pain in the future. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: I take it, IsMemberState, is a property in the Country table?

Comment: Derek, yes that is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case the mistake was made in wrong EF model. MemberState and Country were in 1-1 relation, hence for EF it was obvious that when ControlPolicy is added a new MemberState (Country) must be also defined. Once the navigator relation was changed to proper m:1 MemberState:Country everything started to work.

Besides I find Rui Jarimba FK suggestion very good. Even though it was not the issue here and it was not applicable in my case due to use of a ChangeTracker. Obviously ChangeTracker would not know about the changes made via FK. However in any other case the use of foreign keys would be very handy and useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the Linq query in `MemberState = context.Countries.First(tt => tt.IsMemberState)` statement.Few days back same error occurred to me with the Find Linq statement. By Google I found the solution which is working fine for me

```
 var zz= context.ControlPolicy.Create().GetType().GetProperty("MemberState").GetValue(cp1);

 context.Entry(dmm.Set<ControlPolicy>().Find(entityKey)).CurrentValues.SetValues(cp1);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix your issue, I may have the wrong idea, but from that error message i would try this :-

```
var country = context.Countries.First();

ControlPolicy cp1 = new ControlPolicy()
            {
                Country = country,
                ControlPolicyLevelType = 2, 
                MemberState = country.IsMemberState,
                OperaModuleType = 2,
                MemberStateIncluded = true,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedByUserId = 1,
            };
            context.ControlPolicies.AddObject(cp1);

            context.SaveChanges();
```